# Parse a text file and output it in a new format

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing

I am trying to learn file parsers using shell script and I have my input file
`input.txt` as

```
 int A[4];   /* 0  16*/
 char B[15];  /* 16 31*/
 /* Padding may be required here */
 long int C[2]; /*32  8*/
```

Is there a way to parse the above `input.txt` to my desired format which looks like this `output.txt` output file:

```
0,int, A[4], 0, 16
1,char, B[16], 16,31
2,long int, C[2], 32, 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input seems to be C-like, so it would be better in theory to parse it with a C parser. If you use regular expressions, even for simple tasks, you have to deal with varying spaces, multi-line inputs, etc. The problem is, C parsers do not parse comments, and you apparently want to do so.

Here is a perl script which gives the expected output for your sample.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
#
BEGIN { $i = 0; }

if (m!^\s*(.+)\s+([^ ]+);\s*/\*\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*\*/\s*$!)
{
    print "$i,$1,$2,$3,$4\n";
    $i+=1
}
```

If you save this script as `script.pl` in the folder where `input.txt` is, use it as such:

```
./script.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk alternative without regex:

```
$ echo "int A[4];   /* 0  16*/" |awk '{gsub(/[/*;]/,"");for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s, %s", (i==1?NR-1:""),(i==NF?$i"\n":$i))}'
#Output:
0, int, A[4], 0, 16
```

Pitfall:

```
$ echo "long int C[2]; /*32  8*/" |awk '{gsub(/[/*;]/,"");for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s, %s", (i==1?NR-1:""),(i==NF?$i"\n":$i))}'
#Output
0, long, int, C[2], 32, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '
   /^\s*\/\*/ and $,=",",next;
   print $a++,join ", ", grep /./, map { m!^/\*+\K(\S*)|([^*]*)(?=\*+/$)|(.+[^;]);?$! } @F
'
```